# How to intsall Mariadb?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, mariadb, akeneo

I am trying to install akeneo on my ubuntu but while installing Mariadb following error is coming.

```
Setting up mariadb-server-10.1 (1:10.1.43-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.1 (--configure):
installed mariadb-server-10.1 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mariadb-server:
mariadb-server depends on mariadb-server-10.1 (>= 1:10.1.43-0ubuntu0.18.04.1); however:
Package mariadb-server-10.1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                      Errors were encountered while processing:
mariadb-server-10.1
mariadb-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How to get rid from it.
Any suggestion or help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **MySql** otherwise you will get such an error install Akeneo

```
Check   | Errors                                                                                     |
+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ERROR   | Install MySQL greater or equal to 5.7.22 and lower than 5.8.0 (installed version is 5.5.5) |
+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

there was a similar problem https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010401659-MariaDB-does-not-start-after-update-on-November-the-5th-Assertion-failure-in-file